# How to make webpack to produce code variants?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project that's using the webpack to produce `index.js` out of `root.js` which in turn depends on `dep.js`. Something like:

```
// ==== dep.js ====
console.log('A');

// ==== root.js ====
require('dep.js');
```

Now I want to modify webpack config to produce 2 files  - `indexA.js` and `indexB.js` depending on 2 different modifications of `dep.js` - `depA.js` and `depB.js`, but leave `root.js` intact or almost intact.

Ideally I'd like to have something like:

```
// ==== depA.js ====
console.log('A');

// ==== depB.js ====
console.log('B');

// ==== root.js ====
require(`dep${VARIANT}.js`)
```

and in `webpack.config.js` have something like:

```
['A', 'B'].map(VARIANT => ...)
```

and result to be `indexA.js` (**without** `depB.js` included) and `indexB.js` (**without** `depA.js` included)

I've checked [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin), but still failed to imagine how this could work together.

Comment: what do you wan't to accomplish? Webpack will only produce other files other than the main file if it is dynamic imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to achieve my goal:

- Inside of `webpack.config.js` use `webpack.DefinePlugin` to inject provided variant value at compile time and also to modify the output so distinct outputs would have distinct variant values injected.
- Modified `webpack.config.js` to make cleaning-up dist directory to be optional
- Use a build tool to run `webpack` twice with different variants injected through environment variables

Comment: This answer would be useful if the samples of webpack.config.js were provided.